# Fix inefficient and difficult query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query in my application that is performing poorly. I think it can be optimzed but my SQL skills are failing me. Here's the query in a sort of meta-sql:

```
SELECT A.Value, count(*)
FROM B
    JOIN A ON B.A_ID = A.ID
    JOIN C ON C.ID   = B.C_ID
WHERE B.C_ID IN (
    SELECT B.C_ID
    FROM C
        JOIN B ON B.C_ID = C.ID
        JOIN A ON B.A_ID = A.ID
    WHERE A.VALUE IN 'string literal'
)
GROUP BY A.VALUE
```

C is a table of vacancies, B is a table of properties of the vacancies and A is a table of property values. The tables have 1 to N relationships. We need to find a list of all other property values (and the number of times they occur) of vacancies that have a certain fixed property value related to it.

Please help in optimizing the query for efficiency.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to join in `C` in either query, unless that is being used for filtering (that is, non matches are being filtered out).  Try this:

```
SELECT A.Value, count(*)
FROM B JOIN
     A
     ON B.A_ID = A.ID
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM B b2 JOIN
                   A a2
                   ON b2.A_ID = a2.ID
              WHERE a2.VALUE = 'string literal' AND b2.C_ID = b.C_ID
             )
GROUP BY A.VALUE;
```